# How can I get rid of unsought data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors, lxml

I've written some code in python to scrape some titles and content under each titles. The scraper is doing fine except for the last container. I expect to parse fields from each container other than the last one. Here I used the word `container` to mean `fieldset` tag and the content within it. However, what can i do to get rid of the data from the last container and continue parsing data from the other ones using css selector, I repeat css selector?

Here is what I tried with:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

res  = requests.get("http://www.webscantest.com/").text
soup = fromstring(res)
for data in soup.cssselect("fieldset"):
    title = data.cssselect("legend")[0].text
    content = [item.text.strip() for item in data.cssselect("a")]
    print(title,' '.join(content))
```

To shake off the data from the last container where `div` tag is noticed, I used selectors like this `for data in soup.cssselect("fieldset:not(div)"):` but still the same. However, I could have used `for data in soup.cssselect("fieldset")[:-1]:` to get the desired results but the container I wanna get rid of needs not to be in the last position always or they may recur several times within.

Here are the elements within which the data I'm after are located (first two are identical but the last one contains div tag):

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>JS tests:</legend>
        <a href="soap/demo/">SOAP SPA page</a>
        <a href="rest/demo/">REST SPA page</a>
        <a href="react/">ReactJS test page</a>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>JS tests:</legend>
        <a href="soap/demo/">SOAP SPA page</a>
        <a href="rest/demo/">REST SPA page</a>
        <a href="react/">ReactJS test page</a>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Basic tests:</legend>
        <div>
            <select name="redirect" onchange="javascript: gotoselect();">
                <option value="pickone">Pick a category </option>
                <option value="hrs">HTTP Response Splitting Tests</option>
                <option value="payment_analysis">Parameter Analysis Tests</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <a href="jsmenu/auto_osrun.php">OS Command Inject Tests</a>
        <a href="jsmenu/cookie_set_coffeepits.php">Java Grinder Tests</a>
        <a href="jsmenu/dynalink_myfiles.php">Directory Browse Tests</a>
        <a href="jsmenu/dynalink_rfplaces.php">Resource Finder Tests</a>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: lxml can also use `xpath`, or you only want `css`?

Comment: @eLRuLL , right you are. I'm only after any solution from css selector.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use xpath with `lxml`, and it comes useful on this case, your code should looks like this:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

res  = requests.get("http://www.webscantest.com/").text
soup = fromstring(res)
for data in soup.xpath("//fieldset[not(div)]"):
    title = data.cssselect("legend")[0].text
    content = [item.text.strip() for item in data.cssselect("a")]
    print(title,' '.join(content))
```

Only the elements without a direct `div` child will be matched.